# How to get the name of the team that is not there in registration table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I had two tables first one is having all team names data and the other is having only selected teams data. Now I want to get the left-out teams that are there in the first table. How to get the expected output in PostgreSQL?

Table 1

```
team name
-----------
team1
team2
team3
team4
team5
team6
team7
team9
team10
```

Table 2

```
team title
-------------
team1
team2
team3
team4
team7
team8
team9
```

**Required output**

```
team name
-----------
team5
team6
team10
```

Comment: If your question is about postgresql, you should remove the mysql tag.

Comment: Use a `NOT EXISTS` expression in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "LEFT JOIN" statement to implement your query.
Let's suppose you have 2 tables :

- Table `teams` with column `team_name` (and probably many other columns)
- Table `teams_data` with the foreign key `team_title` to table `teams` and many other columns

Now with the LEFT JOIN statement your query is:

```
SELECT teams.team_name
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN teams_data ON teams_data.team_title = teams.team_name
WHERE teams_data.team_title IS NULL;
```

The important parts are:

- `LEFT JOIN` because it retrieves all rows from second tables respecting the `ON` clause **and also** not respecting this clause but in this case with all columns set to null
- `WHERE ... IS NULL` because this statement filters only the rows not in teams_data